# Why did they use article in the phrase "a workers' cooperative"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article

Why did they use article in this sentence below?

[image]

> The factory is now a workers' cooperative.

Why did they use an article before the word (workers)? Which is plural? 
Does the article ***a*** refer to workers, plural, or refer to cooperative?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. :) How could it refer to *workers'*, which is plural? Also compare: "She accidentally went into a men's washroom."

Comment: The article marks (belongs with) the noun _cooperative,_ not with the modifier _workers'._

Answer (score 1):

"workers'" is plural possessive.  It is saying that the cooperative belongs to many workers.  The "workers' cooperative" is a single thing and requires the article 'a'.